# How to use forked git project in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, git, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am switching from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio`. I have couple of 3rd party libraries that I have added features or modified a little bit. Since the libraries in `Eclipse` are also projects and we can access the code, I had no problem.

In Android Studio `compile` tag in `dependencies` is great but in my case I cannot use it unfortunately.

I fork the project and made necessary changes and add the project as a module in Android Studio. Since the library project already has `settings.gradle` and example and library modules, there is a mess in my project and it does not compile at all.

Has anybody experienced such a problem? What to do and what is the correct way to forked libraries?

Comment: You're going to have to be much, much more detailed about how your project is set up and what errors you're seeing. "I tried something and it didn't work" isn't enough to go on.

Comment: This is not a question like "I have this problem please solve it". This is an opinion question. I am asking that what is the right way when you add a forked github project.

Comment: @pskink i am also stuck  in this .Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What we've done in my project is create gradle scripts for our dependencies that don't have them, and modify the gradle scripts for dependencies that do have them. Gradle does not play very well with modular dependencies, unfortunately: Each sub-project must know its place in the larger overall project. Since you've already forked the github project, modifying it further shouldn't be a problem.